# How to evenly space the grid on a matplotlib log scale

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, logarithm

How can I set the scale of a log-scaled axis in matplotlib to show values less than base^1 and space them evenly?

**Example**:

I have a scale that looks like this:

[image]

But I want a scale that looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your yaxis doesn't make sense, as a log scale has `0` at minus infinity.  You can set a tick position at `0.01` via `ax.set_ylim(ymin=0.01)`. This would have the same distance to `0.1` as the distance between `0.1` and `1`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_yscale('log')
x = np.linspace(0.05, 100, 1000)
ax.plot(x, x, 'r--')
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(lambda x, pos: f'{x:g}')
ax.set_ylim(ymin=0.01)
plt.show()
```

[image: example of log scale y]

Comment: Would it make sense if I was using a symmetric log scale? ie `ax.set_yscale('symlog')` ?

Comment: A 'symlog' scale has 3 parts: the positive part similar to the log scale, a negative part as a mirrored log scale, and in-between a short linear part to unite both. The linear part is needed to work around the impossibility to continue till minus infinity. It is controlled by two parameters: `linthresh` (the place where the scaling jumps from logarithmic to linear), and `linscale` (the length of the linear part as a ratio of the distance between two major logarithmic ticks).  'symlog' will have zero at the center of the linear part, but won't have logarithmic tick marks in that zone.